# Click GeckoAnchorElement in GeckoIFrameElement or change OffsetLeft of GeckoIFrameElement

Tags: c#, iframe, geckofx

In the page I browse with `GeckoWebBrowser`, there's a iframe. I can set a `GeckoIFrameElement` reference on it, access all of the elements. But when I call a `Click()` on a `GeckoAnchorElement` in the iframe nothing happens (but no error thrown). This element, when clicked by mouse, changes the `OffsetLeft` of iframe to hide it.

Is there any way to get the `Click()` working in a iframe ? If not, how can I change the iframe's OffsetLeft ?

(For the record, I should point out that I get clicks to work on elements that are not on the iframe)

Comment: The element witch you want to clicked is some button or some link and its contains in an other element? for example in a div? is like bellow code? <iframe .....> <div><button>Please click me!</button></div></iframe>